# RedGate Error : Error creating window handle

Tags: redgate, ssms-2014

I am using redgate to commit the database changes. But whenever I open SSMS, I am getting this error.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this. I tried restarting application twice. Cleared temporary files. Restarted the system also.

Comment: Me and another co-worker are having the same issue with SSMS 2014 and Redgate SQL Source Control v 5.4.2.4269 trial.